# Expo: Android app icon having a blue background

Tags: android, react-native, expo

So Im coding an react-native app with expo, and I cant get my icon working. It always looks like this:
[App Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPl3V.jpg)

No matter how I change the resolution or the shape of the icon, it will always have that blue outline, what I think is the background.

Here is my app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Tube",
    "slug": "Tube",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./app/assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./app/assets/icon.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#242525"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./app/assets/splash.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#242525"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./app/assets/logo-icon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to modify the "backgroundColor": "#242525"  to see if the color change ?

Comment: This is already modified, its the background color of the icon its self